# How to find out the 'group' name of a Hadoop user?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

User `rok` uploaded file and set the permission to 770. The file on HDFS looks like this:

```
-rw-rw---- 3 rok hdfs  filename1
```

I'm using `ksc` user to consume the data uploaded by `rok` user. So first, I'd like to make sure that `ksc` has permission for that file `filename1`.

How do I find out the group name of my user `ksc`? Does user belong to `hdfs` group in Hadoop?

BTW, if I upload a file to Hadoop, the file permission looks like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 3 ksc ksc filename2
```

The local info on my Linux of `ksc` user is :

```
uid=504(ksc) gid=502(ksc) groups=502(ksc)
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the command below:

`$hdfs groups ksc`

It gives all of the groups user `ksc` belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS follows the traditional style of Linux file system permssions. To determine the group of ksc, use `groups ksc` if you are on Linux.

`-rw-rw---- 3 rok hdfs filename1` will give you read/write permissions only if you are part of the hdfs group. Judging from your output, I'm thinking you're not.

You will need to do one of the following:

- Change rok's file permissions to `664` (read permissions for all users), which is pretty insecure
- Have ksc added to the `hdfs` group, more secure

The choice is yours...

Consult the following links for more information:

http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/hdfs_permissions_guide.html

Comment: Hi luminous, "To determine the group of ksc, use groups ksc if you are on Linux.".  Do you mean run the command on linux terminal "$groups ksc" ? or on linux run hadoop command sth like "hadoop ... groups ksc..."? Thanks

Comment: Though I am 'ksc' user and 'ksc' group on local linux, I can move/delete the file of filename1 which is "-rw-rw---- 3 rok hdfs filename1", it looks like 'ksc' is not in group 'hdfs' it should not have such permission , why it can move it ?

Comment: Verify permissions on the outer directory are as you expect. Other than that it's difficult to say without looking at how things are setup on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Hadoop maps users to groups is configurable, so HDFS groups may not be the same as the Unix groups.  Also note that if your Hadoop configuration does use the Unix user-group mappings, it will use the unix mappings on the NameNode.  Also note that the NameNode caches the mappings for a period of time, so any changes you make may not be available until the cache is expired/refreshed.

As for checking, in addition to what is already mentioned you can check the actual system file that contains the mappings like this if you have root access:

```
grep <user or group> /etc/group
```

More here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/GroupsMapping.html